# How do I have a custom scroll bar on a div (overflow:scroll)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To start with, I am trying to mimic a social engineering website. So far, so good, have I implemented the conversation system with PHP (with a touch of Jquery-Ajax). Anyway now for the messages window, where the messages of a specific conversation were to be loaded, I had the overflow:scroll property to that box because it was overflowing after a certain amount of messages. Now there's a scroll bar, Bravo! But I want my custom scroll bar. Preferably one that I make in PS. Is there a CSS solution to this? Something like 'scrollbar-image:url('custombar.png')"

I know that most of you will suggest me to go make one in javascript. But I don't want to for the following reasons
1) I'm not good enough with that language and it would be a daunting process
2)Why reinvent the wheel when there already is a solution?

See that scroll bar in facebook conversation's area? That gray sexy son of a lady-dog, I'm looking for something like that. Enlighten me?

Comment: PS I am doing it just for my blog. The source code will be public for studying/improving/using on your own site. :)

Comment: The fast answer is "kinda". You can't use an image but you can style them, the problem is that each browser has a different way of doing it. I think your best bet would be to use a jquery plugin. That way it will be tested and the it will require a small amount of work, without reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a list of all the pseudo classes that are available in css to style the scroll bar.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar  
::-webkit-scrollbar-button  
::-webkit-scrollbar-track  
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece    
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb 
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner
```

Using these css properties you can style the scroll bar however you wish even like the one in Facebook's contacts menu.

Here's a start;

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {  
    width: 12px;  
}  
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {  
    background-color: #eaeaea;  
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;  
}  
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {  
    background-color: #ccc;  
}  
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {  
    background-color: #aaa;  
}
```

Which will result like the one in the image below.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! But where do I apply them?
body{
::-webkit-scrollbar
::-webkit-scrollbar-button
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
background-color: #eaeaea;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
background-color: #ccc;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
background-color: #aaa;
}
} // doesn't work

Comment: These are pseudo css classes which means you can use them just as they are in a css file like you would do for selecting any html element, this(http://jsbin.com/jitise/1/edit) links to an example please be sure to view it.

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't work. Doesn't work in that example of yours either.

Comment: My Example still works, with a <div> having a custom Scrollbar just not styled like you mentioned in the question.
I have also made that code into a gist, please if the jsbin is not working try this out: https://gist.github.com/skadimoolam/936d6d8d84cf252585e4

Comment: Yours is just a div with a scroll bar having a lot of unnecessary lines of code. I achieved the same scroll bar on a div with 
overflow:scrolling; 
I was talking about having a custom STYLED scroll bar like the facebook inbox has.
As a matter of fact the scroll width and the likes of those properties. They are not working at all and that is exactly what I am trying to achieve.